# Delay saving picture on gallery

Tags: java, android

Wassup Guys, i'm doing a college project, and my app is a meme generator. After the text plotted, i'm trying to save the image pushing the button. The toast appears, but, it takes more than an hour to the pic show on the gallery. How can i make this thing save immediately?

So there are my codes to create the button listener and the store function

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            View content  = findViewById(R.id.lay);
            Bitmap bitmap = getScreenShot(content);
            currentImage = "meme" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
            store(bitmap, currentImage);
            share.setEnabled(true);
        }

    });




    public void store(Bitmap bm, String fileName){
    String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Memes";
    File dir  = new File(dirPath);
    if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    File file = new File(dirPath, fileName);
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "SALVOU ARROMBADO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "DEU RUIM VACILÃO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `MediaScannerConnection` like below .Create a method `refreshMedia()` -

```
public void refreshMedia(){

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ApplicationContext.context, new String[] { imageFile.getPath() }, null,
              new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                //gallery refreshed.
                  Log.i(TAG, "Scanned " + path);
                }
              });
           }
        }, 1500);  //this is to refresh media after 1.5 second delay

}
```

Here `imageFile.getPath()` is path for your image.

Use it as below-

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

             store(bitmap, currentImage);
            //after saving image call refreshmedia()
             refreshMedia();
        }
```

Comment: So i put this code into `public void store(Bitmap bm, String fileName)`, or declare below `save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` and call it inside `public void store(Bitmap bm, String fileName)`?

Comment: call this after a delay , you can check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The last two things. imageFile should be a new var created? And what about ApplicationContext? It should be a method like store()?

Comment: You can simply pass `context` or `YourActivity.this` there.

Comment: I didn't understand your question about `imageFile` .

Comment: I mean, what type imageFile should be

Comment: `imageFile` is File-   `File imageFile=new File("path of your image");`
You can directly use `path` if you have ,instead of `imageFile.getPath()`